# I randomly get no output at <h1> and <Li> when scraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib import response
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

# headers = {
#     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
# }

csv_file = open("scifi_audible.csv", "w")

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["title ", "link ", "rating ", "reviews "])

url = "https://www.audible.de/"

audiobooklinks = []

for x in range(1, 2):
    source = requests.get(f"https://www.audible.de/search?node=16245852031&page={x}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "lxml")

    audiobooks = soup.find_all("h3", class_ = "bc-heading")
    for item in audiobooks:
        for link in item.find_all("a", href=True):
            audiobooklinks.append(url + link["href"])


#testlink = 'https://www.audible.de/pd/Mortarion-The-Pale-King-Hoerbuch/B0BCQXVJML'

for link in audiobooklinks:
    r = requests.get(link) #headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    
    try:
        title = soup.find("h1", class_= "bc-heading").text.strip()
    except:
        title = "no output possible"

    try:
        rating = soup.find("span", attrs={"aria-hidden":"true", "class":"bc-text"}).text.strip()
    except:
        rating = "no rating"

    try:
        raw_reviews = soup.find("li", class_= "bc-list-item ratingsLabel").text.strip()
    except:
        raw_reviews = "no raw_reviews"

    try:
        reviews = raw_reviews.split("(")[-1].split()[0].replace(".", "")
    except:
        reviews = "no reviews"

    print(title, link, rating, reviews)

    csv_writer.writerow([title, link, rating, reviews])
    
csv_file.close()
```

Most of the time it works. Randomly it is printed i.e. like this:

"no output possible https://www.audible.de//pd/Mortarion-The-Pale-King-Hoerbuch/B0BCQXVJML no rating no"

What do I have to change to always get the h1 and li?

Comment: Is that url behind a login?

Comment: No, the html can be accessed without a login

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, code works fine, behavior is not reproducible and question may need some more details to clarify.

Comment: @HedgeHog - I am able to reproduce the behavior - they did say it doesn't happen *most* of the time

Comment: @Driftr95 Noticed the *it doesn't happen most of the time* in my opinion it still needs more details. Feel free to light us up with additional information.

Comment: @HedgeHog It's usually a 503 error - I've suggested a solution for it, though I  don't have any explanation for the 200-OK-but-empty-content scenario...

Comment: @Driftr95 - That would have been the information I would have expected from the question, thank you very much for that. On what basis does your figure of 2% refer? It would be interesting because even with the 1000 requests I used for testing (delayed and non-delayed), not one ran into this error.

Comment: @HedgeHog I also ran 1k requests [50x20] - 17 got 503 and 2 had 200 ok but empty content. I wonder if the location or user's internet conditions can have anything to do with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248956/discussion-between-driftr95-and-hedgehog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to reproduce the *"no output possible"* scenario, I got it about 2% of the time; it was nearly always due to [503 Service Unavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) error; occasionally, status was 200 [OK], but content was empty - and I don't really know what might be causing that. (Btw, when working with requests, you should generally check that `status_code==200` before proceeding.)

One way to handle this would be to append , something like

```py
repeats = 0  # initiate
maxRepeats = 10 # limit allowed errors

abl_copy = audiobooklinks[:] # preserve original
for link in abl_copy:
    r = requests.get(link) #headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    if r.status_code != 200 or not r.content:
        print(f'! {r.status_code} {r.reason} - for {link} !')
        repeats += 1
        if maxRepeats < repeats: 
            print('! Stopping because of too many bad responses !')
            break
        abl_copy.append(link)
        continue
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    # rest of your for loop
```

There are many other ways to handle it as well - you could add a [wait](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep) every time you get 503, you could add all the bad responses [`r`] to a list and explore/handle them after the loop, etc...

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. After appending your code, there have been no further issues!